# Classic API NVP, Classic ASP DoDirectPayment in Sandbox

Tags: paypal, asp-classic, paypal-sandbox, express-checkout, paypal-nvp

I'm getting the following error when running a DoDirectPayment method in the sandbox. The same code is actually working fine in the live version.

```
WinHttp.WinHttpRequest error '80072f7d'

An error occurred in the secure channel support
```

BTW, the endpoint I'm using is:

```
API_ENDPOINT    = "https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp"
```

I found a post that recommends to change:

```
Set objHttp = Server.CreateObject("WinHTTP.WinHTTPRequest.5.1")
```

by

```
Set objhttp = Server.CreateObject ("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0")
```

In that case the response is:

```
TIMESTAMP=2016-08-11T17:04:06Z&
CORRELATIONID=aa25568f7686b&
ACK=Failure&
VERSION=63.0&
BUILD=000000&
L_ERRORCODE0=10759&
L_SHORTMESSAGE0=Transaction cannot be processed.&
L_LONGMESSAGE0=Please use a different payment card.&
L_SEVERITYCODE0=Error&
AMT=4.00&
CURRENCYCODE=USD
```

By the way, I have tested with more than one card. i.e:

```
MasterCard 5555555555554444
MasterCard 5105105105105100
Visa 4111111111111111
Visa 4012888888881881
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the issue. I was using testing card numbers from paypal provided in this site:

https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/vhelp/paypalmanager_help/credit_card_numbers.htm

Instead of using that, I got the numbers from the following site, and everything goes fine.

http://www.getcreditcardnumbers.com/